# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token Y in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing

I have an array:

```
var newquestions;
questions = ["Item1","Item2","Item3","Item4","item5"];
```

I save the array to localstorage like this:

```
localStorage.setItem("newQuestionsArray", JSON.stringify(questions));
```

I try to get the array like this:

```
newquestions = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("newQuestionsArray"));
```

However it gives this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried running  `localStorage.getItem("newQuestionsArray")` in the browser console to view the output?

Comment: Also this may be a typo, but in your "setItem" call there is an extraneous space at the end of the key.

Comment: I didn't get any error using your code

Answer (score 1):

You can try with below things to check the error:

1. Finding out the [size of localStorage](https://cdmckay.org/finding-out-the-size-of-localstorage) and compare with your json object.
2. You don't want to stringify large objects into a single localStorage entry. That would be very inefficient - the whole thing would have to be parsed and re-encoded every time some slight detail changes. Also, JSON can't handle multiple cross references within an object structure and wipes out a lot of details, e.g. the constructor, non-numerical properties of arrays, what's in a sparse entry, etc.

   In my [`codepen`](https://codepen.io/NullPointerr/pen/mjrepO) its working correctly here.

Comment: Sorry I added that when writing this question, in my code there is no space I have updated it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your code where you set the item

```
localStorage.setItem("newQuestionsArray", JSON.stringify(questions));
```

There is a space after newQuestionsArray .. remove that

---

It should work fine if there was no space.. Or else the do you have huge data in that variable. I think the maximum size of data cannot be more than 4kb. So it might be the issue while storing

Comment: Sorry I added that when writing this question, in my code there is no space I have updated it in the question.

Comment: It should work fine then.. Or else the do you have huge data in that variable. I think the maximum size of data cannot be more than 4kb. So it might be the issue while storing

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your array in an object. (Put `{` and `}` around the array)
It may help to try logging the contents before decoding them to see if what you put in is actually what you get out